# Tables side by side with big curly brackets

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, brackets

I'm trying to re-create the following design in LaTex:

[image: Desired result]

How could I do it?

Comment: Welcome to SE. It's better to ask precise questions about specific points. If you don't know where to start, you should first read a [tutorial on TikZ](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and then come back here with questions about your attempts. Thank you.

Comment: @SimonDispa [Tags are about questions, not answers.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8928)

Comment: If you're not feeling comfortable with TikZ and/or nicematrix, there are other ways (e.g. `colortbl` and math-mode), however TikZ makes it really easy to place things precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many way to do this. Here's a vanilla TikZ solution that uses

- the [`matrix` library](https://tikz.dev/library-matrix) for the `matrix of math nodes` style and the `left delimiter` key and
- the [`positioning` library](https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.5.3) with a `node distance` of `1em` (vertical) and `5em` horizontal which gets used with `above right` and `below right`.

The coloring is done with a [`path picture`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#sec-15.6) which is basically any TikZ drawing that is put behind a node (or a matrix in this case).

Since the content of your matrices is pretty uniform, I'll set up the `pooling matrix` style so that it right-alignes its cells' nodes' content but uses a fixed width of two figures (`text width=width("00")`). If you're using more complex matrix content, this will need to be adjusted.

The `path picture` works that easy because I also assume the matrix are made out of 2x2 fields that are equal in size.

The line

```
\path[local bounding box=right side] (top.north-|top-label.west)
                               (bottom.south-|bottom-label.west);
```

constructs a tight node with the name `right side` of the shape `rectangle` that encompasses the two specified coordinates where [`<c1>-|<c2>`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.3.1) is the point that is horizontal to `<c1>` and vertical to `<c2>`.
For more complex operations in this form, the [`fit` library](https://tikz.dev/library-fit) can be used.

I reference this node named `right side` with `late options` to add the `[left delimiter][3]` on the left.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
  tight matrix/.style={every outer matrix/.append style={inner sep=+0pt, outer sep=+0pt}},
  four colors/.style={path picture={
    \path[4c top left/.try] (path picture bounding box.north west) rectangle (path picture bounding box.center);
    \path[4c top right/.try] (path picture bounding box.north east) rectangle (path picture bounding box.center);
    \path[4c bottom left/.try] (path picture bounding box.south west) rectangle (path picture bounding box.center);
    \path[4c bottom right/.try] (path picture bounding box.south east) rectangle (path picture bounding box.center);}},
  define four color fills/.style n args={4}{
    4c top left/.append style={fill=#1},    4c top right/.append style={fill=#2},
    4c bottom left/.append style={fill=#3}, 4c bottom right/.append style={fill=#4}},
  pooling matrix/.style={
    tight matrix, matrix of math nodes, four colors,
    cells={nodes={draw, align=right, text width=width("00")}},
    row sep=-.5\pgflinewidth, column sep=-.5\pgflinewidth,
    Label/.style={label={[pooling matrix label]above:##1 pooling}}
  },
  pooling matrix text/.style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily, inner sep=.1666em},
  pooling matrix label/.style={name/.expanded=\tikzlastnode-label, pooling matrix text}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  define four color fills={blue!50}{orange!50}{green!50!gray}{red!50!gray!70!white},
  node distance=1em and 7em,
]
  \matrix[pooling matrix] (left) {
    8 & 7 &  5 &  3 \\
   12 & 9 &  5 &  7 \\
   13 & 2 & 10 &  3 \\
    9 & 4 &  5 & 14 \\ };
  \matrix[pooling matrix, above right=of left.east, Label=Max] (top) {
    12 & 7 \\ 13 & 14 \\ };
  \matrix[pooling matrix, below right=of left.east, Label=Average] (bottom) {
    9 & 5 \\ 7 & 8 \\ };

  \path[local bounding box=right side] (top.north-|top-label.west)
                                 (bottom.south-|bottom-label.west);
  \path[every delimiter/.append style={name=brace,xshift=.5em}]
     (right side) [late options={left delimiter=(}];
  \draw[-{Stealth[round]}, thick, shorten <=1pt] (left) -- (brace) node[
     pooling matrix text, midway, align=center, above] {$2\times2$ pooling\\stride 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This solution requires two steps: **(1)** the construction of the three matrices and **(2)** the layout of the matrices  and the insertion of the rest of the elements.

For the first step I used the `nicematrix` package. It allows to choose and change the configuration and the decorative elements of the array without touching the content of the cells of the tabular. This is a nice feature if you generate the array elsewhere and insert it into a `LaTeX` document.

For convenience I defined three commands with the square arrays to be able to change them without interfering with the `tikz` layout.

The second step was done  with a `tikzpicture` using standard `tikz` commands for the arrow, the labels, and relative positioning of the elements.

[image: f]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    
\newcommand{\matrixA}{%     
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{4}{c}}[hvlines,rules/width=2pt, cell-space-limits=1.5ex,columns-width=5ex]
    \CodeBefore % color the blocks
    \rectanglecolor{blue!15}{1-1}{2-2}
    \rectanglecolor{green!15}{3-1}{4-2}
    \rectanglecolor{orange!25}{1-3}{2-4}
    \rectanglecolor{red!15}{3-3}{4-4}
    \Body   
    \RowStyle[nb-rows=4]{\bfseries} % make all bold
    8&7&5&3\\
    12&9&5&7\\
    13&2&10&3\\
    9&4&5&14\\      
\end{NiceTabular}
}

\newcommand{\matrixB}{% 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{2}{c}}[hvlines,rules/width=1.6pt,cell-space-limits=1.5ex,columns-width=5ex]
    \CodeBefore % color the cells
    \cellcolor{blue!15}{1-1}
    \cellcolor{orange!15}{1-2}
    \cellcolor{green!15}{2-1}
    \cellcolor{red!15}{2-2}
    \Body   
    \RowStyle[nb-rows=2]{\bfseries} % make all bold
    12&7\\
    13&14\\     
\end{NiceTabular}
}

\newcommand{\matrixC}{% 
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{2}{c}}[hvlines,rules/width=1.6pt,cell-space-limits=1.5ex, columns-width=5ex]
    \CodeBefore % color the cells
    \cellcolor{blue!15}{1-1}
    \cellcolor{orange!15}{1-2}
    \cellcolor{green!15}{2-1}
    \cellcolor{red!15}{2-2}
    \Body   
    \RowStyle[nb-rows=2]{\bfseries} % make all bold
    9&5\\
    7&8\\       
\end{NiceTabular}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % layout the matrices
    \node (matA) {\matrixA};
    \node[ above right = -30pt and 150pt of matA, scale=1.2, anchor = south west] (matB) {\matrixB};
    \node[ below right = -20pt and 150pt of matA, scale=1.2, anchor =north  west] (matC) {\matrixC};
    % a large parenthesis
    \node (paren) [right = 120pt of matA] {$\left(\rule{0pt}{130pt}\right.$};
    % the arrow
    \draw[-latex,ultra thick,  shorten >=3mm, shorten <=2mm,] (matA.east) -- (paren.center)  node[midway,above, text width=3cm,     font= \bfseries, text centered] {2x2 pooling, stride 2};    
    % add the labels
    \node[above =  -3pt of matB.north,font=\bfseries]{Max pooling};
    \node[above =  -3pt of matC.north,font=\bfseries]{Average pooling};
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```